# Problem building / compiling intel media driver for alder lake i5 12500 on ubuntu 20.04. Please help

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics

I have intel i5 12500 alder lake. I had installed ubuntu 22.04 but I encounter few annoying problems, although the intel driver works out of the box on this version. Anyway I decided to installed 20.04 instead, however latest stock intel media driver is 20.1.1 and it doesn't support alder lake.

I already installed kernel 5.18.6 via tuxinvader ppa.

Now I'm trying to build my own intel media driver 22.3.1, which is the latest driver that support alder lake. However I encounter a lot of problem while doing so.

I followed the building guide in https://github.com/intel/media-driver

output of `cmake ../media_driver`

```
~/software/driver_intel/media-driver-intel-media-22.3.1/build_media$ cmake ../media_driver
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
*BUILD_TYPE not defined, default to: release
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:86 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/user/software/driver_intel/media-driver-intel-media-22.3.1/media_driver/media_driver/cmake/media_defs.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /media_utils.cmake


-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Found X11: /usr/include   
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
CMake Error at media_top_cmake.cmake:29 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /media_gen_flags.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:95 (include)


CMake Error at media_top_cmake.cmake:30 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /media_feature_flags.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:95 (include)


-- Checking for module 'igdgmm>=12.0.0'
--   Found igdgmm, version 12.1.0
-- media -- PLATFORM = linux
-- media -- ARCH = 64
-- media -- CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR = /home/user/software/driver_intel/media-driver-intel-media-22.3.1/media_driver
-- media -- INCLUDED_LIBS = 
-- media -- LIB_NAME = iHD_drv_video
-- media -- OUTPUT_NAME = 
-- media -- BUILD_TYPE/UFO_BUILD_TYPE/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = release/release/Release
-- media -- LIBVA_INSTALL_PATH = 
-- media -- MEDIA_VERSION = 
-- media -- X11 Found
-- Checking for module 'libva-x11'
--   Found libva-x11, version 1.14.0
CMake Error at media_top_cmake.cmake:65 (media_include_subdirectory):
  Unknown CMake command "media_include_subdirectory".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:95 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/software/driver_intel/media-driver-intel-media-22.3.1/build_media/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Upon observing the error, it seems there's problem with CMakeLists.txt

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:86 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/user/software/driver_intel/media-driver-intel-media-22.3.1/media_driver/media_driver/cmake/media_defs.cmake
```

I never build my own driver, so I hope someone with build expertise can help me build the driver.

Comment: the alder lake driver is fully suported by the kernel so there should not be any reason to change this,https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/02/ubuntu-20-04-4-new-hardware-support/

Comment: When I first installed 20.04, The display resolution was only 800x600. I had to install 5.18 kernel to fix this. Then when I check `vainfo`, it show error something like this `libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit` which leads me to believe the driver is not there.

Comment: @trondhansen from you link. It says Add support for Alder Lake P graphics (ADL-P). When I googled what (ADL-P) is, It seems to be alder lake series for laptop. Mine is desktop. Perhaps it still doesn't support the desktop variant?

Comment: i migt be wrong in my asumption that the driver are the same for desktop and laptop version of alder lake.